# Generating unique list per user per day

Tags: php, random

I am building a system that takes a random set of records from a large database, displaying only a handful. I would like the user to receive a random selection of these each day, but for this random selection to be the same for that day. I would also like each user to receive a different random selection.

I believe this to be something based on a random number generator that takes into account the date + userid, but I am unsure how to proceed?

Comment: What have you got so far and what have you tried? Since you are using a database, why are you not saving the random selection (or some sort of reference) to the database.

Comment: This is my problem! Normally I would make a start, but I have no idea what logic/concepts produces these sorts of results

Comment: Generating a random number is easy (google php random number). Then just loop through a given number of times, and use the random number to pick a record each time, perhaps storing it in an array. Then store that information in a table in your database, alongside the user id. When your user comes along, perform a query that looks for their user id in that table and displays the records associated with it.